# Trying to mount/fix/recover apfs volume(s) with corrupted size

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, mount, apfs

I bought an external disk, and installed macOS on it on March 2019. My user home directory which I backed up from my old Mac is also in that. Since September, I cannot mount this disk on MacBook Pro. Here is the status:

```
% diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                             Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            205.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 47.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.3 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         1.1 TB     disk2s2
   3:           Linux Filesystem                         536.9 GB   disk2s3
   4:                 Linux Swap                         37.6 GB    disk2s4
   5:          Apple_CoreStorage apstrg                  2.2 TB     disk2s5
   6:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s6

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2

/dev/disk4 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS apstrg                 +2.2 TB     disk4
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s5
                                 8D18D634-4177-4F13-B35E-5F112402DD12
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

I am interested in  of `/dev/disk2s2`. I have then tried `fsck`:

```
% sudo fsck_apfs -d -ln /dev/disk2s2
** Checking the container superblock.
** Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
** Checking the space manager.
error: spaceman cib out of order: 0, expected 18
   Space manager is invalid.
** The volume /dev/disk2s2 could not be verified completely.
```

I have also used `apfs-inspect` tool its output is at https://pastebin.com/EjHMrpY2 Unfortunately, `apfs-inspect` tool cannot really go back to any checkpoint.

I want to believe that this is fixable. If this file system has snapshots/checkpoints, then I must be able to go back to a point back in time.

<s>In its current broken state, it's possible to list files, and even read contents of those with all these third-party tools.</s> iBoySoft Data Recovery can list files, and show contents. I consider copying files out like that, but I would prefer actually fixing the issue. I am open to all suggestions other than wiping out the entire disk.

Comment: Your `apfs-inspect` output shows that the latest version of the block that lists the contents of `/` is corrupted. Your success with iBoySoft shows that prior versions of this block do indeed exist on the disk, allowing you to recover your files. Until such time as I implement checkpoint-backtrakcing in `apfs-inspect`, actually fixing the structures/getting back your files without grabbing each of them manually will be a more involved process. I'll update you if/when this functionality is added.

Comment: In the meantime, if you'd like to explore the structures yourself and see if you can get anywhere, there's the `apfs-explore-...` tools which should allow you to find older versions of the corrupted blocks.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have even taken steps to fix it (fixed the out of order CIB, recalculate hash), but then fsck failed elsewhere. I wanted to take an image of a single volume in the container, but that didn't work. The next step is to take a copy of this disk into an identical disk, then re-format this drive, and extract only useful things from the identical disk. I might operate on the new disk instead of modifying the original.

Comment: You don't need to mess around with any checkpoint data / Ephemeral objects, as they're not necessary for accessing your data, only for keeping track of the state of the APFS container whilst one or more volumes are mounted. Due to the nature of APFS, you won't be able to image a single APFS volume, only an entire APFS container.

I would definitely create a backup image of the disk or APFS container in its current state so that you can work on that rather than the affected disk itself, as well as then being able to revert back to the original state if you accidentally mess up something.